# Using Subquery select to get column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
p.fsym_id, 
b.p_co_sec_name_desc AS Company_Name,
p.p_date,
p.p_price AS Unadjusted_Price,
b.region AS Region,
f_splitadjprice(p.fsym_id,p.p_date,p.p_price) AS O_Split_Adjusted_Price,
f_prevunadjprice(p.fsym_id,p.p_date,Previous_Date,p.p_price),
(
SELECT MAX(f.p_date)
FROM fp_v2_fp_basic_prices AS f 
WHERE f.fsym_id = p.fsym_id AND f.p_date<p.p_date
)  Previous_Date

FROM
fp_v2_fp_basic_prices p

LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT r2.region, b2.p_co_sec_name_desc, b2.fsym_id
        FROM  fp_v2_fp_sec_coverage b2
        LEFT JOIN sym_v1_sym_region r2 ON b2.fsym_id = r2.fsym_id
        WHERE r2.region = "EUR") b
        ON b.fsym_id =p.fsym_id;
```

I get the error, "Previous_date not on column list" when trying to call the function f_prevundadjprice. Basically what I want to do is create the column previous date using (SELECT MAX..) and then use the value from this column in the function f_prevunadjprice.

Comment: Use a subquery.  You can't use an alias in the same `select`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How would you rewrite the query? I tried but I could not get it to work. Also, why is the same SELECT? I have the (SELECT MAX..) in parentheses, so does this not get computed first? is this not already a subquery?

Comment: Posting a broken query without telling us what you are trying to do will not help us help you.  Tell us what you try to do so that we can get a better understanding.  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Eric I tried to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

you already have one subquery. If you were using TSQL you could outer apply the second one. MySQL doesn't support apply, so you'll have to left join to it:

```
SELECT 
p.fsym_id, 
b.p_co_sec_name_desc AS Company_Name,
p.p_date,
p.p_price AS Unadjusted_Price,
b.region AS Region,
f_splitadjprice(p.fsym_id,p.p_date,p.p_price) AS O_Split_Adjusted_Price,
f_prevunadjprice(p.fsym_id,p.p_date,Previous_Date,p.p_price),
PreviousDate.maxdate

FROM
fp_v2_fp_basic_prices p

LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT r2.region, b2.p_co_sec_name_desc, b2.fsym_id
        FROM  fp_v2_fp_sec_coverage b2
        LEFT JOIN sym_v1_sym_region r2 ON b2.fsym_id = r2.fsym_id
        WHERE r2.region = "EUR") b

        ON b.fsym_id =p.fsym_id;

LEFT JOIN (

SELECT f.fsym_id,f.p_date,MAX(f.p_date) as maxdate
FROM fp_v2_fp_basic_prices AS f 
group by f.fsym_id, f.p_date
)  Previous_Date

on  Previous_Date.fsym_id = p.fsym_id and AND Previous_Date.p_date<p.p_date
```

Comment: How is SQL reading this query? What is being done first? The use of parentheses also looks weird to me. There is a missing ).

Comment: HI Chris, amended the missing bracket. So SQL gets all the data from fp_basic_prices. It joins to the results of the first subquery as a table, aliased as b.. Then joins to the results of the second subquery which gets all of the maxdates grouped by fsym_id, but is joined to by that Id so only one value is returned to the end result.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **p.** to reference all the fields coming from fp_v2_fp_basic_prices , you should also do it in the next line:

```
f_prevunadjprice(p.fsym_id,p.p_date,Previous_Date,p.p_price)
```

try to change it by:

```
f_prevunadjprice(p.fsym_id,p.p_date,p.Previous_Date,p.p_price)
```

If you continue with the same error, you should ensure the table/view **fp_v2_fp_basic_prices** has a column named **Previous_Date**

You should also use AS here:

```
(
SELECT MAX(f.p_date)
FROM fp_v2_fp_basic_prices AS f 
WHERE f.fsym_id = p.fsym_id AND f.p_date<p.p_date
)  Previous_Date
```

So:

```
...) AS Previous_Date
```

Comment: The table fp_v2.. does not have a column named Previous_Date. Please check my updated question :)

Comment: In that case the error is right, there's not any column called Previous_Date in column list. What you can do is to pass to the function the value of Prevuious_Date (SELECT MAX(f.p_date)...). Another way is to pass only f.p_date to the function, and calculate the Previous_Date inside the function...